# Flask-CLI can not run application?

Tags: python, flask, flask-cli

I'm developing a REST API, using flask and flask-restful. I am currently having problems with flask-cli, since in the company environment I can not run with the application. What may be the problem?

In the enterprise, we use conda environments, for python 3 applications. Currently the environment for api consists of python 3.6.8 with flask 1.0.2 and flask-restful 0.37, running on a CentOS 7. Even recreating the environment by requirements or enviroment.yml of the conda, I could not run the application, different from my personal machine that is an ubuntu 18.04, with miniconda3 and env python 3.6.8, with the same flask packages and I can test without problems.

Error:

```
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 325, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 313, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 302, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 317, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 372, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/home/user/opt/miniconda3/envs/comands/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 246, in locate_app
    'Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name)
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "main".
```

Script Main:

```
from app import create_app, db
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = create_app('development')
Migrate(app,db)

@app.shell_context_processor
def shell_context():
    return dict(
        app = app,
        db=db
    )
```

Script **init**.py:

```
from flask_restful import Api
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    api=Api(app, prefix="/api/v1")
    db.init_app(app)

    from app.resources.catcherDicts import Catcher
    api.add_resource(Catcher, "/catcher")

    return app
```

I wan to be able to run the tests and run the application in the company environment. Because even exporting the application path with `export FLASK_APP = main.py` command `flask run` cannot run the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

is telling you it can't find the `main.py` module from your `cli.py` module. This is happening because you set your entry point to your application as `main.py` with this line of code: `export FLASK_APP = main.py`. I suspect this environment variable is incorrect, I would try running your entry file directly and seeing if it works, if so your environment variable is incorrect. Additionally, ensure your `<path>` is set appropriately if you're not running the file from the directory containing your entry point otherwise `flask run` will not work.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Many thanks Nathan, you're correct, in fact my problem is being in the moment that I inform you the location of the main.py script. Based on the documentation, it is not clear that I need to enter the full path to environment variable. Soon I was only informing the location of the script and running ```flask run``` inside the folder, but it still would not run the application.
With your solution, I needed to enter the full path and now it worked! Many thanks for the reply.

Comment: Please Nathan, add this information, insert the full path, for when others are reading this doubt. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Np glad you were able to get it to work! Just added the part about the path :)

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was with a environment. I uinstall Flask, and MySQL and install it again with and updgraded subversion. It worked for me.